# Cannot find type "DatabaseReference" in the scope

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui, connection

I am using xcode 13 and I have set up to connect realtime database with swift ui app my wish is to write data to firebase but to this step I am getting error
Here is my  to config firebase

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
@main
struct FirebaseDatabaseApp: App {
    init(){
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

And file contentview.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        var ref: DatabaseReference! //I have a err here
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I try to create new class on another file but it still not work
[image]
how can i achieve the goal of writing data to realtime database,
I was following firebase docs

Comment: I would assume you need to `import FirebaseDatabase`

Comment: That line should not be in a body put it in a class of some kind. Bodys are only for SwiftUI views. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) You seems to be missing the very basics

Comment: I was try two method but it still doesn't work

Comment: I am facing the same issue, and *import FirebaseDatabase* is not available, I am using swift with Xcode 13.3.1.